# Help with compiz window borders

Tags: 11.10, unity, window-manager, conky

I tried to make a small change in my Compiz settings, and set off a whole chain of chaos.

I don't like the application switcher that I had, that switched between whole applications on Alt-tab rather than individual windows. I'm not totally sure whether that was Unity or not, but I used to have one that I really liked, back in Gnome 11.04: I'd hit alt-tab and I could see all my open active windows, alt-tab through them or pick one with the mouse. I keep mucking with my Compiz settings trying to get that back.

I haven't managed to find it but I did manage to do something to hide or kill all my window borders. I've got windows with no borders, and no way to get minimize/maximize/close buttons. How do I get the borders back?

I think that I did the following:

- enable application switcher and try to resolve the conflicts in "alt-tab" and "alt-shift-tab" in favor of the application switcher (they were in conflict with the unity plugin)
- Change the reveal mode to "bottom" from "left" -- this caused a conflict with Desktop Wall. I tried to resolve the conflict and was left with Desktop Wall disabled completely.
- I've tried turning "unity grab handles" on and off. Neither seems to have an impact.

(PS. I tried running `unity --replace`. Didn't help. Is there a way to dump my compiz settings so someone can look at them?)

Comment: You should be able to run `unity --reset` to reset all unity settings. It will help if you can be more specific about which options you changed. Lots of compiz settings can have this as a side effect.

Comment: okay, `unity --reset` got me a functioning desktop enviroment but even ate my display settings. I'll update the question to describe the changes.

Comment: There is the window decoration plugin.

Comment: But that wasn't on before.

Comment: Okay, the window decoration plugin helped a lot. But everything is still totally wonky.

Comment: Aleksandar ... that gave me what I actually wanted, window wise, instead of restoring what I had. So I'll accept it as an answer if you make it one. Off to start a new question about application switchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the window decoration plugin to restore window borders and minimize/maximize/close buttons.