# Where did my display configuration go?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

I'm troubleshooting a [huge unity headache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74186/help-with-compiz-window-borders), and ran `unity --reset` which had the effect of somehow crapping out my dual monitor settings and leaving me with mirrored displays. I can't seem to get things back the way they were (and there aren't that many options with two monitors). Does anyone know if my display settings are secretly backed up someplace? I haven't logged in or out.

Comment: I got it back with <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>F7</kbd> but wtf?

Comment: Can you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it back with <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>F7</kbd>, but I don't know where it went.